# Can't access global variable in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multi processing library in python in code below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
from time import sleep as delay

test = "First"

def f():
    global test
    print('hello')
    print("before: "+test)
    test = "Second"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
    delay(1)
    print("after: "+test)
```

It's supposed to change the value of `test` so at last the value of test must be `Second`, but the value doesn't change and remains `First`.
here is the output:

```
hello
before: First
after: First
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is because p is a new *process*, not a new *thread*. When you spawn a new process, it copies your initial process's state completely and then starts executing in parallel. When you spawn a thread, it shares memory with your initial thread.

Since processes have memory isolation, they won't create race-condition errors caused by reading and writing to shared memory. However, to get data from your child process back into the parent, you'll need to use some form of inter-process communication like a pipe, and because they fork memory, they are more expensive to spawn. As always in computer science, you have to make a tradeoff.

For more information, see:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Based on what you're actually trying to accomplish, consider using threads instead.

Answer (score 2):

Global state is not shared so the changes made by child processes has no effect.

**Here is why:**

> Actually it does change the global variable but only for the spawned
>   process. If you would access it within your process you can see it. As
>   its a process your global variable environment will be initialized but
>   the modification you make will be limited to the process itself and
>   not the whole.

**Try this** It explains whats happening

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
from time import sleep as delay

test = "First"

def f2():
    print ("f2:" + test)

def f():
    global test
    print ('hello')
    print ("before: "+test)
    test = "Second"
    f2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=())
    p.start()
    p.join()
    delay(1)
    print("after: "+test)
```

If you really need to use modify from the process their's another way of doing it, read this [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/python-multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent) it might help you.