# Python concurrent.futures - writing to a global variable in parent process

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I want to use `concurrent.futures` together with `numpy` to manipulate two `scipy.sparse` matrices:

```
matrix_A = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((1000, 1000), dtype=np.float32) 
matrix_B = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((500, 1000), dtype=np.float32)
```

The algorithm works like this: every row in `matrix_B` has a one-to-many relationship to rows in `matrix_A`. For every `row_B` in `matrix_B`, I find its corresponding `[row_A1, row_A2 ... row_An ]` in `matrix_A`, sum them up and assign the sum to `row_B`.

```
def update_values(row):
    indices, values = find_rows_in_matrix_A(row)
    matrix_B[row, indices] = values
```

The matrices are large (10^7 rows), and I'd like to run this operation in parallel:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
     futures = {row : executor.submit(update_values, row) 
                for row in range(matrix_B.shape[0])}
```

But this doesn't work because changes made by child processes to global variables will be invisible to the parent process (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/python-multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent)).

Another option would be to return the values from `update_values`, but that would require merging the values in the parent process, which takes too long for my use case.

Using `multiprocessing.Manager.Array` could be a solution, but that would create copies of the matrices at every write, and given their size, that's not an option.

Is there any way to make `matrix_B` writeable from child processes? Or what would be a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Is `matrix_A` stored on disk? Or built when the algorithm starts? What about the list of row relationships? Also, this seems to be CPU-bound work, so 32 workers is likely going to slow you down unless you actually have a 32-core machine.

Comment: How much do you know about the format and math of sparse matrices?  Do you know how they differ from numpy arrays?  It would be good, I think, to demonstrate this action without the multiprocessing, and may be even without sparsity.  Then add the sparsity and multiprocessing one by one.

Comment: @bnaecker I have a 32 core machine. `matrix_A` is built when the algorithm starts, same with the list of row relationships.

Comment: @hpaulj what do you mean by `demonstrate this action`? When developing the algorithm, I initially single thread/process with numpy array, the algorithm works as expected.