# Global variable not updated in python while using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I have a following simple code

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
x = []


def func(a):
    print(x,a)


def main():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    pool = Pool(1)
    global x
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    ans = pool.map(func,a)
    print(x)
```

It gives me the result

```
[] 1
[] 2
[] 3
[] 4
[] 5
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I expected the result to reflects the change in global variable x.
Which seems that the changed in global variable `x` is not updated before the pool call. I would like to ask what is the cause of this?

Comment: why do you think x is being used in pool? you don't use `x` with pool in any way here.

Comment: In function "func" I just print the value of "x".

Comment: `Which seems that the global variable x is not used in the pool at all`: This is because x is not used in pool at all. This is what I am getting at. Maybe your wording is misleading to your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing global variable updates not returned to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/python-multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because this is multiprocess, not multithread. the main process and the new process does not share a same global variable. So the new process has the copy of the main process when x is [], and after created, main process change x's value, but it does not change to new process's x.

if change the code to this :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
x = []


def func(a):
    print(x,a)


def main():
    a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    global x
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    pool = Pool(1)
    ans = pool.map(func,a)
    print(x)
```

and the ouput will be what you want. 
Notice the **pool = Pool(1)** 's position

Comment: Sadly I have the same result. Would you mind to check if things work with your computer?

Comment: I checked. and if the pool = Pool(1) is before x's change, the output is same as yours. and if I move this code down, the output will be ([1,2,3,4],i) .... And I run this on ubuntu  64 and python 2.7.

Comment: This might be the cause of different version, I use python 2.7.

Comment: read carefully please, I use python 2.7 also. and I mentioned it. If you understand what happens, you will be supposed to different result. Hopefully you can find why your output is same and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

So I have done what GuangshengZuo suggested, and sadly the result was not desirable. After looking deeper into it, I realized the problem was not because of script, but rather the OS.

In windows, there is no [os.fork()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork), hence the change in global variable is not copied. But, on Unix machine, the script works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Two seperate processes will not share the same global variables. A multiprocessing pool abstracts away the fact that you are using two seperate processes which makes this tough to recognise.