# Using globally declared tuple for Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am having some trouble using a tuple globally with the multiprocessing class.

I have a code as produced below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jj = ()
    def f(x):
        global jj
        jj += (x*x,)

    # Section A
    #for ii in range(20):
    #    f(ii)
    #print (jj)

    # Section B
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(f, range(20))  
    pool.join()
    print (jj)
```

If I run section only B, I get the tuple jj as an empty tuple. However, if I run only section A, I get a tuple of length 20.

Why is that so?

Comment: Please run either section A or section B at a time. Comment out the other section not in use. I use tuple because in my original code, I have to store a lot of variables and I read that the instantiation of tuples is much faster than a list. I am not calling these values anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as [Python multiprocessing global variable updates not returned to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/python-multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent) explains, global state is not shared among processes.

You can share state using, for example, `multiprocessing.Queue`.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jj = ()
    q = Queue()

    def f(x):
        global jj
        jj += (x * x,)

    def f_multi(x):
        q.put(x * x)

    # Section A
    for ii in range(20):
        f(ii)
    print(jj)

    # Section B
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(f_multi, range(20))
    pool.close()

    stop = "STOP"
    q.put(stop)
    items = []
    for i in iter(q.get, stop):
        items.append(i)

    print(tuple(items))
```

Alternatively you can use `print(tuple(sorted(items)))` to get the values in the same order as `Section A` will produce. 4 processes are working on the task in `Section B` and hence the "unordered" result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually @Dušan, the problem which I am facing is that I don't have a single variable I'd have to put in a Queue.

I have a function that generates a lot of data. I'm trying to store that data from each iteration so that I can use them later on for validating/checking my results. Is there any efficient way to do that?

It seems to be that I'll have to do this for each of the variables.

Comment: You can put all variables you want to return from your function to a `dict` and then put that dict to the `Queue`, e.g. `q.put({'data1': [1,2,3], 'data2': (0.5, 0.6)})`.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. If I can make the function return this dictionary then I don't even have to use a queue.