# Is it possible to have multiple processes write to the same dictionary using Pool.map()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, global-variables, python-3.6

I'm using python3.6 and am trying to execute the something similar to the following code. However, after execution the variable `mydict` remains `{}`

I've tried this with `global mydict` and without. I thought that dicts were global by default, but neither seems to work.

```
mydict = {}
def TEST(hello, integer):
    global mydict
    mydict[integer] = hello
    print(integer)
with closing(Pool(processes=4)) as pool:
    pool.starmap(TEST, [['Hello World', i] for i in range(200)])
```

Is it possible to have multiple processes write to the same dictionary in python?

Comment: `MultiProcessing` pickles to separate processes. When it does that I'm not sure it pickles the globals. It might be possible to just return the `integer, hello` values and pass those along to another starmap for processing. update see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056415/2026508

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is is possible to have multiple processes write to the same dictionary in python?*

No, it's not possible to share dictionaries between processes because each one runs in a separate memory-space with the Python code involved being interpreted by different copies of the interpreter—although that can be done via shared memory for some other data-types.

However, it can be simulated by using a [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to coordinate updates to certain kinds of shared objects—and one of the supported types is `dict`.

This is discussed in the [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) section of the online documentation. Using a `Manager` involves a lot of overhead because they're run as a separate server process in parallel with any other processes your code creates.

Anyway, here's a working example based on the code in your question that uses one to manage concurrent updates to a shared dictionary. Since what the `TEST()` function does is so trivial, it is quite possible that doing it this way is slower than it would be *not* using `multiprocessing`, due to all the extra overhead it entails—however something like this would likely be appropriate for much more computationally-intensive tasks.

```
from contextlib import closing
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def TEST(mydict, hello, integer):
    mydict[integer] = hello
    print(integer)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Manager() as manager:
        my_dict = manager.dict()

        with closing(Pool(processes=4)) as pool:
            pool.starmap(TEST, ((my_dict, 'Hello World', i) for i in range(200)))
```