# Multiprocessing and global keyword

Tags: python, multiprocessing

So I was just curious about the multiprocessing library in python. If I did something like

```
 results = pool.map(multi_run_wrapper,[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)])
```

If in my function I declare global variables, are they maintained to the specific instance, or since they are global they could screw with eachother over the several different calls when running simultaneously?

I was hoping that one call would have its own namespace, etc so that there wasn't this interaction between the different calls.

Comment: As far as I know, when using multiprocessing, each Process has its own copy of the program and data.

Comment: docs - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes
interesting article with tech details https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing global variable updates not returned to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055303/python-multiprocessing-global-variable-updates-not-returned-to-parent)

Comment: Did you try it?